# Read localStorage data in AppModule

Tags: angular

I want to bootstrap different component manually in AppModule based on data stored in localStorage.

I googled a lot and got way to manually bootstrap the component.

https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/ways-of-bootstrapping-angular-applications-d379f594f604

```
// create DOM element for the component being bootstrapped
// and add it to the DOM
const componentElement = document.createElement('d-comp');
document.body.appendChild(componentElement);

// bootstrap the application with the component
app.bootstrap(ComponentDynamic);
```

But now I'm unable to localStorage methods like (setItem and getItem) as it does not idetifies localStorage.

Can anyone please help me this?

Answer (score 0):

`LocalStorage` can be found on `window`.
If you don't have access to window in some reason, create some service for obtainining window like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {

   getWindow(): Window {
      return window;
   }
}
```